# How to split an ident into letters in Rust macro?

Tags: rust, matching, rust-macros

I need to write an `multiply` macro which converts ident into single letter idents and multiply them.

```rust
let a = 4;
let b = 7;
println!("{}", multiply!(abbabbb));
// println!("{}", (a * b * b * a * b * b * b))
```

but I dont know how to match a single letter.

I want to do something like this:

```rust
macro_rules! multiply {
    ($id:letter$other:tt) => {
        $id * multiply!($other)
    };
    ($id:ident) => {
        $id
    }
}
```

Comment: Macro hygiene prevents `multiply` from accessing variables defined outside of it.

Comment: Only with a proc macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it in pattern-matching macros (as in your example), only in [procedural](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) macros.

Even in procedural macros solving your problem will be quite hacky. In Rust an indent is a single indivisible element of AST, so to convert one indent to many you'll first have to convert it to `String`, divide it into characters and convert the characters back to indents.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in a `macro_rules` macro. The closest you can do is to add spaces between the idents:

```
macro_rules! multiply {
    ($($id:ident)*) => {
       1 $(* $id)*
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = 4;
    let b = 7;
    println!("{}", multiply!(a b b a b b b));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=1f2710928c8e012907be2b80cd7e8d9b)